# how to include imagecontrol in sqldatareader by using loop

Tags: asp.net

```
SqlConnection cnn = klas.baglan();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" Select * from aracResimler where ilanID=3028", cnn);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
    { 

    Image[] imageArray = new Image[dr.FieldCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.Length; i++)
        {
        imageArray[i] = new Image();

        imageArray[i].ImageUrl = "~/Images/800/" + dr[2].ToString();

        Panel1.Controls.Add(imageArray[i]);

        }

    }
```

I could not see what I get images include the panel1

Comment: I've cleaned up the formatting of your question a little, but it's still not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: "Select * from aracResimler where ilanID=3028" this is my sql query which is has 9 images. But I cannot display all of them. my question is that my logic correct or no? I did not find What's wrong? thank youu